# How to set Tilda as the default terminal?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, configuration, tilda

I am looking for a way to make `tilda` my default terminal. It would be achieved with

```
# update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
There are 5 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm               20        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/lxterm                   30        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/uxterm                   20        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/xterm                    20        manual mode
```

`Tilda` does not appear in this list though properly installed.

How is this list generated and how do I add `/usr/bin/tilda` in it?

Comment: See [this link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81992/better-way-to-add-alternative-using-update-alternatives) on U&L Stack Exchange. Possible duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the link. What would be the `<link>` in the command `update-alternatives --install <link> x-terminal-emulator /usr/bin/tilda  0`

Comment: `/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator`

Answer (score 3):

1.Add `tilda` to the list of terminals:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /usr/bin/tilda 0
```

2.set `x-terminal-emulator` to `tilda`

```
update-alternatives --set x-terminal-emulator /usr/bin/tilda
```

PS: valid on Ubuntu 16.04